# How can I output formset as a result of submition of another form?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, formset

I am trying to output formset as a result of another form submission on the same page.

This formset contains forms that should be submitted too.

Here is my func view:

```
def manage_articles(request):
    dyn_form = type('DynForm', 
                (forms.BaseForm,),
                {'base_fields': {'title': forms.CharField(), 'name': forms.CharField()}})


    form = ArticleForm()
    formset = formset_factory(dyn_form, extra=4)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ArticleForm(request.POST)
        formset = formset(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if formset.is_valid():
            print('Formset sent')
        if form.is_valid():
            return render(request, 'test_form.html', {'formset': formset, 'form':form})
    else:
        return render(request, 'test_form.html', {'form':form, 'formset': ''})
```

Here is my basic form:

```
class ArticleForm(forms.Form):
    author = forms.CharField()
```

Currently, I get an error when I submit the first form:

```
['ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with']
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Your code looks like it's already doing what you describe. Can you give more details? What exactly do you observe and what do you expect?

Comment: @ascripter added error description

Comment: I have a suspect: Have a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/formsets/#understanding-the-managementform. Does it help?

Comment: @ascripter thanks, useful link, but decided to use client-side